# Replacing characters after percent sign with regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to use RegEx to replace all text that comes after the percent sign in a string.
Let's say I have the following string:

```
/path/to/webpage/%foo
```

I would like to use RegEx to replace `%foo` (this is variable and doesn't necessarily contain foo at all times) with `$foo`.

So far I have come up with the following expression, except this doesn't seem to work.

```
(%([a-z]+))\w
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an easier pattern, no `(` subpattern matching needed here, just `%.*$` for 'match all characters starting from '%' to the end of line':

```
<?php
$name = "/path/to/webpage/%foo";
$pattern = '/%.*$/';
$bar = 'bar';
$new_name =  preg_replace($pattern, $bar, $name);
echo "$new_name\n";
```

result:

```
/path/to/webpage/bar
```

Comment: Thank you. Had to tweak it a little as I need a back reference so grouping was necessary. This is what I was looking for. No idea who down voted, it got me to the right answer.